# Snowflake Connection to Sagemaker - CloudFormation error on StorageIntegrationStack when creating

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to associate Sagemaker with snowflake using AWS CloudFormation, by following this tutoriel : https://quickstarts.snowflake.com/guide/vhol_snowflake_data_wrangler/index.html?index=..%2F..index#2
but while creating the stack I got this error :

*StorageIntegrationStack

CREATE_FAILED
Embedded stack ... was not successfully created: The following resource(s) failed to create: [KMSKey, SnowflakeSecret].*

What's KMSKey and SnowflakeSecret ? How can I fix this error ?

Comment: Could you please share the parameters that are used to create various Stack objects?

Comment: @FKayani what parameter do you exactly want ? I'm not a security expert, and I don't know which parameter can be safe to share.

Comment: I mostly follow the tutorial adapting at my account
I let the default value of pDomainName 
I think i got a unique pExternatStageBaseName
I didn't add pSecurityGroups
I took the first of the three pSubnet proposed
I let the defaultvalue of pTemplatesURL
I add a prefix to the default value of pUserName
I took the only VPC available
I putt my own snowflakeAccount like id.region
I put the password and the snowflake role and user I want to use (like in the tutorial)

Comment: Please check the log from the yaml script for the Storage Integration Cloud Formation Template

and verify if the Key Management System(KMS) based keys were defined for it?

Comment: By checking the log of StorageIntegrationStack I got : 
KMSKey CREATE_FAILED Resource handler returned message: "Access denied for operation 'CreateKey'."

SnowflakeSecret CREATE_FAILED User: ...  is not authorized to perform: secretsmanager:CreateSecret on resource: SnowflakeSecret

Does this mean I need to add authorization to the IAM User ?

Comment: I got this issue fix, but I have a new one with the FullKernelBuilderStack : 

BaseStack : The following resource(s) failed to create: [S3SyncFunction].


SageMakerStudioStack : The following resource(s) failed to create: [StudioDomainPublic]. 

I don't find any documentation on the internet to fix this